# Android Retrofit: missing method body, or declare abstract

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I am writing an android app that will use Retrofit to make API requests.

I have a helper class like this:

```
public class ApiService {
    public static final String TAG = ApiService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://myapiurl.com";

    public static void testApi(){
        ApiEndpointInterface apiService = prepareService();
        apiService.ping(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response apiResponse, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                Log.e(TAG, apiResponse.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.e("Retrofit:", error.toString());

            }
        });

    }

    private static ApiEndpointInterface prepareService() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .build();
        ApiEndpointInterface apiService =
                restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

        restAdapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
        return apiService;
    }

}
```

And my actual Retrofit implementation is simple:

```
public class ApiEndpointInterface {

    @GET("/v1/myendpoint")
    void ping(Callback<Response> cb);
}
```

The problem is, I cannot build the project, I get the error:

```
Error:(12, 10) error: missing method body, or declare abstract
```

Referring to my ApiEndpointInterface class.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `public interface` for your API declaration.

```
public interface ApiEndpointInterface {

    @GET("/v1/myendpoint")
    void ping(Callback<Response> cb);
}
```

Also, looks like you're creating your ApiEndpointInterface before telling the builder to set log level to full.

```
private static ApiEndpointInterface prepareService() {

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
            .build();

    ApiEndpointInterface apiService =
            restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

    return apiService;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you update to okHttp Version 2.4.0 , you will get an exception for empty Body as latest version no more allows zero length  request , in which case you would have to use the following syntax

public interface ApiEndpointInterface {

```
@GET("/v1/myendpoint")
void ping(Callback<Response> cb, @Body String dummy);
```

}

call

```
 ApiEndpointInterface apiService =
            restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

 apiService.ping(callback,"");
```

Ref
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/751